# linq get multiple values at certain conditions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am using this query to get the values in certain values on the basis of certain conditions..

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = gridviewdt.NewRow();

    dr[0] = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(l => l.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id)
        .Select(l => l.Field<string>("description"))
        .First()
        .ToString();

    dr[1] = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where row.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id
             select row).Count();

    dr[2] = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where row.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id && row.Field<int?>("status") == 1
             select row).Count();

    dr[3] = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where row.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id && row.Field<int?>("status") == 2
             select row).Count();

    dr[4] = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where row.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id && row.Field<int?>("status") == 3
             select row).Count();

    griddt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

These above statements takes more time to execute the queries multiple times in the loop & also datatable `dt` contains hundreds of thousands of records. I want it to be something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_curing; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = gridviewdt.NewRow();

    dr[0] = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(l => l.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id)
        .Select(l => l.Field<string>("description"))
        .First()
        .ToString();

    data = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(l => l.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    dr[1] = g.Count(),
                    dr[2] = (g.Field<int?>("status") == 1).Count(),
                    dr[3] = (g.Field<int?>("status") == 2).Count(),
                    dr[4] = (g.Field<int?>("status") == 3).Count()

                });

     gridviewdt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Is it possible to write in above way or any other best possible manner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is slow, because you are making several queries, while you can do the one.

This code will only make one query and store result in an array. Then, you can safely use this data.

Also, you don't need `for` loop, if `i` is limited to the count of `items`:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    DataRow dr = griddt.NewRow();

    var data = dt
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(l => l.Field<int?>("ID") == item.curing_id)
        .Select(l => new {
            description = l.Field<string>("description"),
            status = l.Field<int?>("status")
        })
        .ToArray();

    dr[0] = data[0].description;
    dr[1] = data.Count();
    dr[2] = data.Count(d => d.Status == 1);
    dr[3] = data.Count(d => d.Status == 2);
    dr[4] = data.Count(d => d.Status == 3);

    griddt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is now working 4-5 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous object like this:

```
var data = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where row.Field<int?>("ID") == items[i].curing_id
            select new
            {
                dr1 =  row.Count(),
                dr2 =  (row.Field<int?>("status") == 1).Count(),
                dr3 =  (row.Field<int?>("status") == 2).Count(),
                dr4 =  (row.Field<int?>("status") == 3).Count(),
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

And the populate your `datarow` like this

```
dr[1] = data.dr1;
dr[2] = data.dr2;
```

Comment: I tried it but getting the error `bool does not contain a definition for Count....`